# laravel production in windows server

Tags: laravel, windows, laravel-7

im new in laravel and i have done my first project, I have xampp,mysql and windows server 2012 (installed with composer and laravel 7). i'm running the application in server via command below

`php artisan serve --host=[ip] --port=[port]`

application is running fine within the network. However, it seems super slow. I'm not sure if this the correct way of deploying it into production. Do you have any recommendation/instructions where can i run/deploy apps within the resource that I  have.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Speed of your laravel project depends on many parameters like hardware config (CPU,RAM,...) and also number of users and level of requests and processes. But consider that for an app in production it's better to not use php artisan serve command. It's only for development environment. I don't that how much you know about linux but I suggest you to change your stack and use linux as your production os with nginx as web server alongside php-fpm for running your app in production. But for now you should config xmapp's  apache web server to run your application from project's public folder. Here is a link you can use: https://insidert.medium.com/setting-up-laravel-project-on-windows-2aa7e4f080da

good luck